# Pcregrep duplicating matching multi-line patterns?

Tags: unix, multiline, dna-sequence, pcregrep

I have a text file which contains 2 lines of a sample DNA sequence, using`pcregrep`, I want to find patterns matching "CCC" especially the patterns that span through multiple lines  *(see end of line 1 to the beginning of line 2 in test.txt below)* .

test.txt:

```
AGAGUGGCAAUAUGCGUAUAACGAUUAUUCUGGUCGCACCCGCCAGAGCAGAAAAUAUUGGGGCAGCGCC
CAUGCUGGGUCGCACAUGGAUCUGGUGAUAUUAUUGAUAAUAUUAAAGUUUUCCCGACAUUGGCUGAAUA
```

Using Command:

```
pcregrep -M --color "C[\n]?C[\n]?C" test.txt
```

Returns:

```
AGAGUGGCAAUAUGCGUAUAACGAUUAUUCUGGUCGCA**CCC**GCCAGAGCAGAAAAUAUUGGGGCAGCG**CC**

**C**CAUGCUGGGUCGCACAUGGAUCUGGUGAUAUUAUUGAUAAUAUUAAAGUUUU**CCC**GACAUUGGCUGAAUA
```

It seems to correctly highlight the 2 C's in line 1, however, it highlights the first C in line 2 and then proceeds to print out the second line entirely; giving me a duplication of C.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I avoid the duplication of 'C' in line 2?

Comment: Will this work for you `pcregrep -M --color "(?<!C)(C\RCC|CC\RC)(?!C)" test.txt`   ?

Comment: I used lookbehind and lookeaged assertions to make sure no extra Cs can be found before and after the 3 Cs, that is, you match exactly 3Cs.If more than 3Cs is impossible in a DNA sequence (I don't know about it), then you may remove the lookeahead and lookbehind assertions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
pcregrep -M --color "(?<!C)(C\RCC|CC\RC)(?!C)" test.txt
```

I'm assuming that you want to find exactly 3 `C`s and no more, and that more than 3`C` is possible. If that is not possible, or you don't care about matching more than 3C's, you may use this simpler regex instead:

```
pcregrep -M --color "C\RCC|CC\RC" test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!C)   # Negative lookbehind: Don't match if there's a C before the match
(              # One of these:
      C\RCC    #   C + any kind of new line + CC
    | CC\RC    #  CC + any kind of new line + C
)
(?!C)    # Negative lookahead: Don't match it there's a C after the match
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NKfr4a/1/).